# didSelectItemAt and didDeSelectItemAt from UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

If I use `didSelectItemAt` in a `UICollectionView`, I want to change the color of the selected cell. And with `didDeselectItemAt`, I want to replace the color of the previously selected cell.

It works well before moving. However, moving to the far right will not work properly. Why is this?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 14 
 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CalendarCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath ) as! CalendarCollectionViewCell

        cell.calendarDayLabel.text = calendar?.twoWeeksDay![ indexPath.row ]
        cell.calendarDateLabel.text = calendar?.twoWeeksDate![ indexPath.row ]

        return cell

 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CalendarCollectionViewCell


        cell?.calendarDayLabel.textColor = UIColor( red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0 )
        cell?.calendarDateLabel.textColor = UIColor( red: 255 , green: 255 , blue: 255 , alpha: 1.0 )
        cell?.calendarCircleImageView.isHidden = false

        self.selectYear = self.calendar?.twoWeeksYear![ indexPath.row ]
        self.selectMonth = self.calendar?.twoWeeksMonth![ indexPath.row ]
        self.selectDate = self.calendar?.twoWeeksDate![ indexPath.row ]
        self.selectDay = self.calendar?.twoWeeksDay![ indexPath.row ]

        self.selectDateTime.text = self.selectYear! + "년 " + self.selectMonth! + "월 " + self.selectDate! + "일 " + self.selectDay!

        self.selectDateTime.isHidden = false

}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CalendarCollectionViewCell
        cell?.calendarDayLabel.textColor = UIColor( red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0 )
        cell?.calendarDateLabel.textColor = UIColor( red: 0 , green: 0 , blue: 0 , alpha: 1.0 )
        cell?.calendarCircleImageView.isHidden = true

 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMBfr.png)

Answer (score 5):

Because cells are reused

```
 var selectedIndex:IndexPath?
```

//

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CalendarCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath ) as! CalendarCollectionViewCell

       if indexPath == selectedIndex {

                cell.calendarDayLabel.textColor = UIColor( red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0 )
                cell.calendarDateLabel.textColor = UIColor( red: 255 , green: 255 , blue: 255 , alpha: 1.0 )
                cell.calendarCircleImageView.isHidden = false

       }
       else {

              cell.calendarDayLabel.textColor = UIColor( red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0 )
              cell.calendarDateLabel.textColor = UIColor( red: 0 , green: 0 , blue: 0 , alpha: 1.0 )
              cell.calendarCircleImageView.isHidden = true

       }


}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedIndex = indexPath
    collectionView.reloadData()

 }
```

Remove `didDeselectItemAt`

Comment: collectionView.reloadItems(at:[oldIndex!,selectedIndex!])      Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Thank you very much. I've got it fixed !!
I want to go further and make the first cell appear to be selected before I select one. Can you teach me?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here? Multi-selection state? Or just a selection state? Either way, you really ought to be subclassing `UICollectionViewCell` and overriding `isSelected` instead of having the collection view delegate manage the look of selection.

For the first example, just enable `allowsMultipleSelection` on the collection view and select cells as they are tapped. You can override `isHighlighted` to give a temporary look to the cell a user is touching.

For the latter, you only need to override `isSelected` and set a color based on this state.

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isSelected {
            calendarDayLabel.textColor = UIColor( red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0 )
            calendarDateLabel.textColor = UIColor( red: 255 , green: 255 , blue: 255 , alpha: 1.0 )
        } else {
            // do opposite color
        }
        calendarCircleImageView.isHidden = !isSelected
     }
}
```

Comment: i want just a selection state not multi selection

Comment: See edited example. You should really let the cell be managing how it looks in selection states. Examples where you do it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are a) inefficient. this requires you to reload cells at index paths that are changing selection state and b) your delegate is responsible for the state of the cell, not the look. It's why `isSelected`, `isHighlighted` are provided as easy override points.

Comment: I did not understand well. ㅜㅜ